# How to assign data to a multi-dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, matrix-indexing

I have a `numpy array` `batch` initialized as follows:

```
batch = np.zeros((50, 60, 1920, 1080, 3))
```

Its supposed to be an array of 50 different, 60FPS videos of dimension 1920x1080, and the 3 represents three channels - red, green, blue. Each video is of exactly 1 second.

I iterate through all videos in my video folder and perform image processing on each frame of every video. Then, I write the transformed video in to the `batch` array. How do I properly index the batch array to save each video conforming with the dimension of `batch` array?

So far I have tried the following:

```
batch[:batches_produced, :idx, :] = frame[:]
```

where `batches_produced` is the current batch item index, `idx` is the current frame's index and `frame` is the actual frame of dimension `(1920x1080x3)`.

When I

`print(batch_data[1,2,:,:,:].shape)`, it throws

`IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`.

Needless to say, this isn't working at all. I have spent most of my day trying to figure this out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To assign one frame (1920,1080,3) to a particular slot in `batch` I think you shoul use: `batch[batches_produced, idx, :] = frame` (no slicing needed).

Comment: You don't define `batch_data` so we can't help you with that indexing error.  But a start would be to `print(batch_data.shape)`.

Comment: hey man thanks!! i did `batch[batches_produced, idx] = frame` and it worked! i think i over-engineered.